# Error encountered inserting into a database in C#

Tags: c#, sql, insert

I am inserting values into a database but i get an error when the value to be inserted has an apostrophe e.g Jo's. How do i resolve this?
This is my code

```
     SqlDataReader readerReference = cmd_Reference.ExecuteReader();

        int loginIndex = readerReference.GetOrdinal("a column");
        int DomCodeLoginIndex = readerReference.GetOrdinal("a column");
        int dom_domain = readerReference.GetOrdinal("dom_domaine"); 
        int emp_surname = readerReference.GetOrdinal("a column");
        int emp_name = readerReference.GetOrdinal("a column");
        int srv_name = readerReference.GetOrdinal("a column");
        int emp_model_tel = readerReference.GetOrdinal("a column");
        int emp_EntryDate = readerReference.GetOrdinal("a column");
        int emp_Telephone = readerReference.GetOrdinal("a column");
        int emp_Mobile = readerReference.GetOrdinal("a column");
        int emp_Email = readerReference.GetOrdinal("a column");


        string insert = "INSERT INTO EMP_tracking(emp_login, emp_dom_code, emp_domain,   emp_affectation_date, emp_surname" +
            ",emp_name, emp_service,emp_telephone_model" +
            ",emp_entry_date" +
            ",emp_telephone_number" +
            ",emp_cellphone_number" +
            ",emp_email) VALUES ('{0}',{1},'{2}','"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss") +"','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}')";




    string toInsert = string.Format(insert, readerReference.GetString(loginIndex),
                                            readerReference.GetInt32(DomCodeLoginIndex ), 
                                            readerReference.GetString(dom_domain),
                                            readerReference.GetString(emp_surname ),
                                            readerReference.GetString(emp_name), 
                                            readerReference.GetString(srv_name), 
                                            readerReference.GetString(emp_model_tel), 
                                            readerReference.GetDateTime(emp_EntryDate), 
                                            readerReference.GetString(emp_Telephone),
                                            readerReference.GetString(emp_Mobile), 
                                            readerReference.GetString(emp_Email)
                                   );      


    cmd_Insert.CommandText = toInsert;
    cmd_Insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Let's say the column concerned is emp_login. How will the solution be implemented on it?

Comment: You have to escape the apostrophe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question comes up over and over again. You should not create SQL strings using concatenation - instead use paremeters:

```
string insert = "INSERT INTO EMP_tracking(emp_login, emp_dom_code, emp_domain,   emp_affectation_date, emp_surname" +
        ",emp_name, emp_service,emp_telephone_model" +
        ",emp_entry_date" +
        ",emp_telephone_number" +
        ",emp_cellphone_number" +
        ",emp_email) VALUES (@emp_login, @emp_dom_code, //... etc.";

cmd_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_login", readerReference.GetString(loginIndex));
cmd_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_dom_code", readerReference.GetInt32(DomCodeLoginIndex));
//etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[Parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6tdby40.aspx)** , that will resolve your issue and will save you from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

See this tutorial: [C-Sharp Database Parameterized Insert Tutorial](http://www.vistadb.net/tutorials/insertrows-csharp.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can try escaping the apostrophe with another apostrophe.

There's a similar question here:  [How to insert a value that contains an apostrophe (single quote)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912095/how-to-do-a-sql-insert-with-a-value-with-an-apostrophe-in-it).

Warning: SQL injection alert. Don't allow db manipulation except through parameters.