# Combining array of strings into one string

Tags: ruby, string

I have the following array of strings:

```
array = [id, message, date, length]
```

Example:

```
array = ["1", "test's message", "2016-01-01", "15"]
```

I want to merge it into one string. I will use that string to insert data in DB using:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute
```

I did:

```
result = "(#{array[0}', '#{array[1]}', '#{array[2]}', '#{array[3]}')"
```

`message` contains special characters `'` (ASCII code 039). This results in SQL exception. How can I construct a `result` string that includes the `'` character?

EDIT:

To put data in BD I use:

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (`id`, `message`, `date`, `length`) VALUES #{result}"
  conn.execute sql
```

EDIT:

I fixed this using AR method:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(message)
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. There is 2016 around an no one sane developer would construct SQL by joining strings.

Comment: At which point is the exception raised? During loading the file? During generation of the string? During SQL query?

Comment: `You are doing it wrong. There is 2016 around an no one sane developer would construct SQL by joining strings.`
Why? I need performance. I want to put data in DB using raw SQL. I don't need AR because I have validated data and I am not scared about Dependency injection because it is simple backgroud job. Tell my why. I have huge amount of data and using plain sql increases inserting 20x

Comment: `At which point is the exception raised? During loading the file? During generation of the string? During SQL query?` exception is rised because I have `'` char in message string. This is why I am asking how merge strings with special characters. You don't need exception message.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. The error is not raised because there is a `'` in the message string.

Comment: I edited message maybe this make it more clear. And yes error is raised because there is special character

Comment: No it is not because of that.

Answer (score 2):

answer is here:

[How to insert a value that contains an apostrophe (single quote)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912095/how-to-insert-a-value-that-contains-an-apostrophe-single-quote)

You basically double up the apostrophe: `"test''s message"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for generate result.

```
array = ["1", "test's message", "2016-01-01", "15"]

result = "(#{array.map{|s| s.gsub!("'", "''"); "'#{s}'"}.join(",")})"
# => => "('1','test''s message','2016-01-01','15')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the special character like this

```
array = ["1", "test''s message", "2016-01-01", "15"]
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `Array#join` [Doc Link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join)

```
arr = [id, message, data, length]
join_result = arr.join(',')
```