# Insert text dynamically with single quotes in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a problem with inserting data text dynamically from one table to another table which can have a single quotes (').

The link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912095/how-to-insert-a-value-that-contains-an-apostrophe-single-quote) cannot be used in my case because the the data is dynamic (from table).

Here's my code in php:

```
...
//select from master table with some condition inputted by user
$sql = "SELECT prod_name, prod_price FROM master_prod WHERE cat_prod ='$category'";

//get all data and insert to another table
$rs5 = $db->GetAll($sql);
foreach ($rs5 as $row) {
    $rs = $db->Execute("INSERT INTO trans_temp (name, price) VALUES ('$row[prod_name]','$row[prod_price ]') ");
}
...
```

My problem is, the `prod_name` data can have single quotes ('), and when it happens, it won't inserted to table `trans_temp` because the `INSERT` code have single quotes (`'$row[prod_name]'`).

Ex.: `INSERT INTO trans_temp (name, price) VALUES ('ICE BON BON 5'S 80GR (1C=24)','130')`

Can someone help me? Thank you for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO is probably much better solution, but you can also use `''` for escaping:

```
$rs5 = $db->GetAll($sql);
foreach ($rs5 as $row) {
    $t1 = str_replace("'", "''", $row['prod_name']);
    $t2 = str_replace("'", "''", $row['prod_price']);
    $rs = $db->Execute("INSERT INTO trans_temp (name, price) VALUES ('$t1','$t2') ");
}
```