# Database backup using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am creating a job which takes backup of a database and with the filename suffixing today's date. But I'm getting below error.

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Query = 'BACKUP DATABASE [DBName] TO DISK = ''D:\Backups\DBName_'+cast(convert(date,getdate())as varchar)+'.bak'
EXEC sp_executeSql @Query
```

**Error Message:**

```
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'D:\Backups\DBName_2017-07-07.bak'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'D:\Backups\DBName_2017-07-07.bak'.
```

Comment: You have unmatched quotes. You probably need to escape them or use double quotes if that's an option.

Comment: Why are you doing backups in this manner?

Comment: Also prolly best not to name you backup with `.txt`  (they are not textual backups, they are a binary format)

Comment: Also see [How to insert a value that contains an apostrophe (single quote)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912095/how-to-insert-a-value-that-contains-an-apostrophe-single-quote)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the last closing quote. It should end in `.txt'''`

```
SET @Query = 'BACKUP DATABASE [MetaCost] TO DISK = ''D:\Backups\DBName.bak_'+cast(convert(date,getdate())as varchar)+'.txt'''
```

Also typically you use the `.bak` extension for a sql database backup.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement will output

*BACKUP DATABASE [DBName] TO DISK = 'D:\Backups\DBName.bak_2017-07-07.txt*

You need to add `'.txt'''`