# Allow single quote in sql query

Tags: sql, codeigniter, quote

I want to update my sql table , but in my case I am getting error look like this

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ivision '' at line 1

```
$name = "A'nme";

$this->db->update("users",["name" => $name]);
```

My project based  on Codeigniter

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a value that contains an apostrophe (single quote)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912095/how-to-insert-a-value-that-contains-an-apostrophe-single-quote)

Comment: look up how to escape special characters ( & ' _ % ) in sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double up and use single quotes to see it better:
[How to insert a value that contains an apostrophe (single quote)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912095/how-to-insert-a-value-that-contains-an-apostrophe-single-quote)

```
$name = 'A''nme';
```

Comment: I dont want to save second quote in my db, I only want 1 quote

Comment: This will output A'nme ... is that not what you want?

Comment: Not. in my db its saving as A''nme

Comment: Are you sure everything is in single quotes ' ?