# String Expression for contractions in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, string

I am trying to search for string expression for a phrase that has a contraction.  It a different deparment so I cannot have them change it to the full words.  I get an error when I try to search for it.

```
"Disposition Name" IN ('Customer Doesn't Qualify')
```

But because of the ' in Doesn't I get an error.  Is there some I can do with REGEXP_LIKE for it to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a value that contains an apostrophe (single quote)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912095/how-to-insert-a-value-that-contains-an-apostrophe-single-quote)

Answer (score 1):

You can just escape the quote ' by replacing it with two single quotes '', for example;

```
"Disposition Name" IN ('Customer Doesn''t Qualify')
```

Comment: Cool sounds easy.  I’ll try it.  Thanks.