# Passing special characters (') in DB query

Tags: android

So i have a data base and in the app while the user searches for something with the **'** character, like "wendy's house", i send a query with the WHERE as "wendy's house" and here is where it crushes.

I would like to know please what should i do with the string in order that ill be able to send it in the query and the result the user gets will stay unharmed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give us the query.

Comment: In the string you write 2 x quotes consecutively so instead of `'` you will write `''` - the result will be `'`

Comment: While escaping apostrophes may work, I think you want to look into prepared SQL statements. This just screams SQL injection to me.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments, problem solved. @nbokmans ill look into it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912100/2065587) you have an answer how to escape the apostrophe in your SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Person
    (First, Last)
VALUES
    ('Joe', 'O''Brien')
              /\
          right here
```

Or

```
SELECT First, Last FROM Person WHERE Last = 'O''Brien'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912100/2065587

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!