# Txt is not importing to Db

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Getting this error when trying to import data from txt to my Db

17 values were expected, but found 13. (near "(" at position 20627)

The line of data where the problem appears is this:
('35','835','835','32','57804','Ex sit at id et.','Fanopoiia','14660.36347','10','Funk','Mixanikos','835','Duchess; 'and most of 'em do.' 'I don't see any.','1982-07-02 141548','7','Nai','1973-01-25 060239'),

Comment: You need to be escaping the apostrophes in your string values.

Answer (score 0):

You may escape the apostrophes with double qoutes: ''

Check [How to insert a value that contains an apostrophe (single quote)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912095/how-to-insert-a-value-that-contains-an-apostrophe-single-quote)