# Searching sql database where the field to search contains single quotes

Tags: quotes

I have a number of tables that are linked by a common field called `StockCode`. The `StockCode` contains maybe one and sometimes 2 single quotes. When I try to read the related tables using the `StockCode` as the key I get an error.

E.g.

```
Table: Stock, field: StockCode = Earl's Stock
Table: Sales, field: StockCode = Earl's Stock
```

If I read the Stock and try to find the StockCode on the Sales Table I get an error.

Comment: Please always include error messages in your question.

Comment: Similar question already answered here ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912095/how-to-insert-a-value-that-contains-an-apostrophe-single-quote